# URI scheme missing from Branch.io $deeplink_path

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

Our Branch.io deep links only open the app but don't navigate to the correct view, since we rely on a pod DeepLinkKit which expects the incoming `$deeplink_path` to include a URI scheme (i.e. `https://` or `appName://`)

The Branch Debugging Tool shows that `$deeplink_path` and `$ios_deeplink_path` both contain the correct URL, but without the needed URI scheme (`appname.com` instead of `https://appname.com`).

I tested a Branch URL with a custom `$deeplink_path` that included the URI scheme and it worked to open the correct app view. Is there anyway to programmatically ensure each Branch link contains a URI scheme in the `$deeplink_path`?

Answer (score 5):

This is Vatsal, from [Branch.io](https://branch.io).

When you set `$deeplink_path` or `$android_deeplink_path` you only need to specify the path value such as "category/bags". Once you click the Branch link and open the browser, we will generate the URI scheme which will look like `urischeme://category/bags?link_click_id=` to open the app.

But, in the link data within *initSession()* method, you'll get `$deeplink_path` as "category/bags" only. There will be no URI scheme appended.

If you are using Android App links or Apple Universal links to open the app, then we will not fire any URI scheme and you will still get `$deeplink_path` as "category/bags" as the deep link data.

The URL `$deeplink_path` you are getting is from the App Indexing tags that you have set in the web URL which is being used as the `$desktop_url`. Branch scrapes the web URL and fetches the app indexing tags you have and sets them as the `$deeplink_path`.

If you have more doubts or if you wish to disable this auto-scraping, please write us at integrations@branch.io and we will take this conversation forward.

Best

Comment: To the original poster's point and your point, @vatsal-bajpai .. it would be great to have a $something which had the original URI scheme so we could pass it straight into our routing library.  Otherwise, we have to do something like `let uclWithScheme = "CARFAXConsumerApp://ucl/\(deepLinkPath)" (well, not the ucl part)` :)